# How to put two plots with inset side by side in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create two plots in Gnuplot side by side using multiplot. The problem is that how can I add inset to each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to point your attention to the gnuplot demo page ([gnuplot demo page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/)), however, I couldn't find an example of such insets in multiplots right away.

Simply use `set multiplot layout 1,2` and continue plotting but with different sizes and offsets. See example below:

**Code:**

```
### multiplot with insets
reset session

set multiplot layout 1,2
    plot x**2
    plot x**3

    set size 0.3,0.3
    set origin 0.1,0.6
    set ytics 0.5
    plot sin(x)

    set size 0.3,0.3
    set origin 0.6,0.6
    plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the following might also be of interest... https://stackoverflow.com/q/65640035/7295599